# How to add props in Storybook.JS to a button like isLarge, isSmall, isBlue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I followed Storybook tutorials and created select controls to add props to the Button component. For example:

```
  export default {
  title: 'Button',
  component: Button,
  argTypes: {
    size: { control: "select", options: ["isSmall", "isLarge"] },
  },
}
```

My code output in Storybook look like this:

```
<Button size="isSmall" />
```

I want my component to be like this:

```
<Button isSmall />
```

If "isLarge" is selected from dropdown it should output:

```
<Button isLarge />
```

Is there a way to do this without "size=" in the output? It can do this with boolean switch, but no luck with dropdown or radio buttons.